# ExtJS: requiring an extra operation on AJAX proxy in addition to CRUD

Tags: ajax, extjs, proxy

Hopefully a simple 'is there an easier way' question.

I have a ExtJS (4.1) model which will always be handled singly, so I have defined the proxy on the model rather than setting up a store.

However, in addition to the CRUD operations in the api configuration, I also want to be able to pull down a set of default values which will come from a 5th url.

We've thought of defining 2 proxies on the object and switching them over if required

```
Ext.define('app.model.Amodel', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: [
       ...
   ],
   crudProxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
      ...  
      api: {
        create: 'urlCreate',
        read: 'urlRead'
        ...
        }
    },
    defaultProxy: {
    ...
      url: 'urlDefault'
    },
    defaults: function(Id) {
       this.setProxy(defaultProxy);
       var params = this.getProxy().extraParams;
       params.Id= Id;
       this.load();
       this.setProxy(crudProxy);
    }
```

Is there a neater way of doing this? Maybe creating a proxy in the defaults function, calling a function on it and setting the model from it? Alternatively is there a way of having the Url of the proxy configured so you can call that instead of the api methods? A direct call like `this.data = this.Proxy.call(url)` would be ideal.